# Get url of product's images (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, mysql, advanced-taxonomy-queries

What happen when a post (product) didnt have a guid,because it has the same image with another product ?

For example:

Query1:

```
select guid from wp_posts where post_type='attachment' and post_parent=num
```

Returns nothing.

Query2:

```
select guid from wp_posts where ID=num
```

Returns the url of product.

In this case how should i find the image url of that product?

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, the GUID is not the URL. It is a "globally unique identifier". WordPress uses the URL for this purpose, but accessing it is not a reliable way to get the URL for anything (this was a bad idea, but is kept this way for backwards compatibility).

It's not possible to query the image URL from the database directly. The full URL is not stored there. But if you have the ID for a product and want to get the URL for its image you can do this:

```
$product   = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );
```

Comment: Thank you,but If i want to find it from database,i mean in which table i can find it?

Comment: As I said, the full URL is not stored in the database. It's programmatically generated based on a few factors, such as the site URL, permalink structure, post type rewrite arguments, upload directory structure, and wp-config settings. You need to get it using a function like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

i have seen some ware a query to fetch products image from database.
may be it will help you.
just set required parameters as per your requirement.

```
SELECT p.ID,am.meta_value FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta am ON am.post_id = pm.meta_value AND am.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish';
```

Answer (score 0):

For your reference just run this query in database :

```
 SELECT * FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key IN ('_wp_attached_file', '_wp_attachment_backup_sizes',  '_wp_attachment_metadata',  '_thumbnail_id')
```

And if you run the above query with "_wp_attached_file" only you will get the path from upload directory.

Hope it helps..